# How to expose a HTTPS port on Heroku?

Tags: java, heroku

I have a Java server running on a Heroku free dyno.

I can see the server running OK in the logs. But the server exposes its user interface via HTTPS. It is not even configurable to use HTTP. And seems like Heroku only allows exposing a single HTTP port from its `$PORT` environment variable. So I cannot access the user interface on `myapp.herokuapp.com`.

Heroku documentation only talks about HTTP port and not HTTPS.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications

Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to expose a HTTPS port on Heroku?

This isn't something that your application needs to do on Heroku.

Just bind to the port given by the `PORT` environment variable. Incoming traffic on ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) will automatically be routed to your application.